# Sql - create entry in table A for every entry in table B

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have table Users model with id. Now i create table(model) Settings which should store settings for every User form Users table. How can i create entry in table Settings for every exist User from Users table?

Column Users:

```
id ;some value ; someothervalue;
```

Column Settings:

```
id ; user_id ; message_1 ; message_2
```

I want to create entry in the table Settings for every User. Right now every new User have before_create filter but old users havent got entry in Settings table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert TableSettings(list of ColNames ...)
Select [list of colnames ...]
From TableUsers
```

Just make sure that the list of colNames in tableSettings match (in the number of columns and datatype) the list of columns in tableUsers.

to start with just the UserId and message_1

```
      Insert tableSettings(userID, message_1)
      Select id, 'A message with someotherValue:' + someothervalue
      from tableUsers
```